# Map a list of tuples as the value to a dictionary key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, mapping

Given a large list of tuples:

```
[
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141)
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168895)
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657169744)
(101484, 'Atlantic City Electric', '704F4C92-58FE-47C9-970E-912319B3AEFF', 1657172630)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657174320)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657174328)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657174343)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657175124)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657175289)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657175359)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657175362)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657175401)
(23835, 'GSMC - Marshall', '1EE66E0C-FDBE-47B8-AA61-1AB2CE62D7E8', 1657175410)
(101484, 'Atlantic City Electric', '704F4C92-58FE-47C9-970E-912319B3AEFF', 1657178517)
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657193884)
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657193897)
]
```

How to iterate through the list and map the tuples as a list of tuples (value) based on the first element of each tuple, so that the final dictionaries will look like:

```
{
    100159: 
[(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168895), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657169744), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657193884), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657193897)]
}, 

{
    101484:
[(101484, 'Atlantic City Electric', '704F4C92-58FE-47C9-970E-912319B3AEFF', 1657172630), 
(101484, 'Atlantic City Electric', '704F4C92-58FE-47C9-970E-912319B3AEFF', 1657178517)]
},

...
```

I have attempted looping through the list of tuples, appending each tuple conditionally, and mapping the new list of tuples based on a specific key:

```
    # tuple
    event_record_values = (siteId, siteName, deviceId, time)

    # temporary array to iterate through all tuples
    event_records_array.append(event_record_values)

  prop_value_array = []
  for t in event_records_array:
    if (siteId == t[0] and siteId in siteToPropsMapping):
      prop_value_array.append(t)
  siteToPropsMapping[siteId] = prop_value_array
```

Which results in:

```
{
100159: 
[(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141), 
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141),
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141),
(100159, 'Rochelle Community Hospital', '4ECB9638-0FA6-45A9-B2C3-EAE6452EBBBA', 1657168141),
<repeating duplicate tuples...>]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dict.setdefault` method to ensure a list is present or added for each key before appending each tuple to each list for each key:

```py
siteToPropsMapping = {}
for record in event_records_array:
    siteToPropsMapping.setdefault(record[0], []).append(record)
```

That's roughly equivalent to:

```py
siteToPropsMapping = {}
for record in event_records_array:
    key = record[0]
    try:
        siteToPropsMapping[key].append(record)
    except KeyError:
        siteToPropsMapping[key] = [record]
```